# Save dropped down value to cookies

Tags: javascript

I have a dropped down button and when chosen will be save to cookie.
I have to save in cookie so that I can redeem in the checkout page.
Have this so far but cant save them to the cookies:

```
    function storeValues(form)
    {
    setCookie("product1",form.product1.value);
            return true;
    }

    </script>
     <ul>
     <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Product1" />
     100% Pure Glutamine Powder</br>
    Ultimate Recovery Fuel!*</br>
    Supports Recovery From Workouts!*</br>


    <form name="myform" action="checkout.html" method="POST">
    <div align="center">
    $12.99</br>
    Select Quantity
    <select name="product1" onchange="return storeValues(this);">>
    <option value="1">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Typo, should be setCookie("product1",form.value);

Comment: Do you have a setCookie function in your code or is this everything you have?

Answer (score 0):

There is no setCookie function in js. You can either use the jQuery cookie library or create your own set cookie function.

Use something like this **(taken from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)**

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```